Why is the discrete exponential function claimed to be a one-way-function?
I'm currently struggling to mathematically accurately define one-way functions and apply it to the discrete logarithm. I'm concerned with the discrete exponential function $e_\alpha: \mathbb{F}_p^*\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_p^*, x\mapsto \alpha^x$ with $\mathbb{F}_p^*=\mathbb{F}_p\setminus\{0\}$ being the multiplicative cyclic group for a prime $p$ and a generator $\alpha$  of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$. I understand that it's significantly harder to calculate the inverse, however in my understanding calculating the discrete logarithm of an element $y$ can be done by simply checking for every $x \in \mathbb{F}_p^*$ if it satisfies $\alpha^x=y$. Since there are only $p-1$ elements and multiplication can be done in polynomial time, doing that would result in an algorithm with a runtime $O(p^2)$, so the discrete logarithm is a problem solveable in polynomial time and therefore belonging to the complexity class $P$.
Given that for a function to be one-way I assumed you need the inverse calculation to be hard (particularly NOT solveable in polynomial time), I don't see how the discrete exponential function would satisfy that criterion.

When dealing with some algorithms it is customary to express its complexity in terms of  the number of digits of the entry. So if you have an algorithm  that is linear on $p$ it's actually called exponential on the size (the number of digits) of $p$.

To be precise, as in the comments, the complexity is evaluated with respect to the size or number of digits, typically bits, of the input to the relevant algorithm.
Brute force checking will require
$$
p-1=\exp\{\log (p-1)\}
$$
steps in the worst case. The computation of the elements $\alpha^x$ will typically be done by square and multiply which takes polynomial complexity (in $\log p$).
Note that the best generic algorithms for discrete log such as Baby Step Giant Step and Pollard's Rho, while more efficient still take on the order of
$$
\sqrt{N}=\exp\{\log (N)/2\}
$$
steps and are of exponential time complexity, in a generic group with $N$ elements. Pollard rho is preferable since it uses negligible memory while BSGS uses $O(\sqrt{N})$ memory.
